# Usage of REGEXP with a token from dictionary for creating an annotation in UIMA

Tags: regex, uima, ruta

I need to mark an annotation with the use of regular expression and a token from a dictionary. Here is my rule

ANY{REGEXP("new"), Book.names.ct == "personal book" -> MARK (NewPersonalBook)};

that has to work with the following input:

1. new personal book application
2. open a new personal book

The programm shows no errors in the code but it doesn't mark the annotation "NewPersonalBook" for the input.
How is it possible to fix the problem?

Comment: I gues the problem could be the second condition, which tries to resolve an annotation of the type Book with the same offsets as the matches annotation of the type ANY. The Book annoation will probably be bigger if it is not the textspan "new". So the condition won't match. Can you extend the example? Maybe something like the following could work: `b:Book{b.names.ct == "personal book", REGEXP(.*new.*) -> NewPersonalBook};`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your case but I tried to replicate what you're trying to do

I created a wordlist

```
personal book, nicebook
```

Then I have my text example

```
new personal book application. open a new personal book. my new nicebook is nice.
```

The script

```
WORDLIST BooksList = 'books.txt';

DECLARE Book, NewBook;

Document{-> MARKFAST(Book, BooksList)};
W{REGEXP("new")} Book.ct == "personal book" {-> MARK(NewBook, 1, 2)}; //if you want to test a specific text
W{REGEXP("new")} Book {-> MARK(NewBook, 1, 2)}; //this will annotate NewBook for a books with the word new before it
```

If you dont want the "new" word with the annotation you need to remove the integer parameters (as they indicate the span that you want covered, in this case the first matched text "new" and the second which will be the book text)

Disclaimer: I'm new to UIMA RUTA, hope this helps